# A curve is contained in a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

I need to prove that if $\alpha: I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is regular with curvature $\kappa$, then $\alpha$ is on a circle with radius $r>0$ if and only if $|\kappa(t)|=\dfrac{1}{r}$.

Comment: No, the usual definition of regular curve, all the derivatives of $\alpha$ are nonzero for every $t$.